# Cant send keys with the selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new at Python and i was just trying to write a code to open new tabs in the browser.So i searched for some ways to do that and i came across this process.But though it works nicely in the youtube videos mine simply doesnt work.It only just opens a new window and goes to google.com.But it does not press the ctr+t to open a new tab. I dont know why cause it doesnt even show any error in the python shell. Was hoping someone could help me with this and tell me what is wrong with my code.Thank you

```
#! python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
elm=browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [code snipped](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903) to open a new tab in selenium:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep    

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com?q=python#q=python')
first_result = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_class_name('rc'))
first_link = first_result.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

# Save the window opener (current window, do not mistaken with tab... not the same)
main_window = browser.current_window_handle

# Open the link in a new tab by sending key strokes on the element
# Use: Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN to open tab on top of the stack 
first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)

# Switch tab to the new tab, which we will assume is the next one on the right
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)

# Put focus on current window which will, in fact, put focus on the current visible tab
browser.switch_to_window(main_window)

# do whatever you have to do on this page, we will just got to sleep for now
sleep(2)

# Close current tab
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

# Put focus on current window which will be the window opener
browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i was hoping if you could tell me that what is wrong with the code that i wrote.

Comment: I think you missed `first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)`